# proof of theorem related to modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

before i will  explain of my question , first of all  let us introduce classical definition of division algorithm ,namely for  given integer  $a$ and integer  $d$, here exist unique integers $q$ and $r$ such that

$0 \leq r <d$

so that   $a=d*q+r$

from where

$q=\frac{a}{d}$

and     $r$ is remainder when we are  dividing $a$  by $d$

now  question about one theorem : namely 
let $a$ and  $b$ be integers and let $m$ be positive integers, then

$${a}\equiv b \pmod {m}. $$

if they  have  same remainder when divided  by $m$

this   $${a}\equiv b \pmod {m}. $$  means  that

$a-b=k*m$

or $a=k*m+b$

compare to  this equation

$a=d*q+r$

$b$ is remainder when  $a$ is divided by $m$, on the other hand

$a-b=k*m$

from here  $b=-k*m+a$

from this equation we know that    when b is divided by $m$,  quotient part is  $-k$ and remainder is $a$, but that means  that $a=b$  ,  as i know  it is not necessary  that $a$  must be equal to $b$ , if they are equal of course

$${a}\equiv b \pmod {m}. $$

as  $a-b=0$ and   $0$ mod  $m$  is equal to zero, so where i am making mistake in my conclusion ?

Comment: yes yes thanks, i will  change

Comment: And I wouldn't write $q=\frac{a}{d}$. That asserts something different from the sentence "$q$ is the quotient when $a$ is divided by $d$, with remainder $r$."

Comment: i  could not express in latex  a div d  and that why

Comment: Better to use language when notation fails, rather than the wrong symbols.

Comment: thanks  @ThomasAndrews now what about theorem itself?

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is due to the statement

'$b$ is remainder when $a$ is divided by $m$, ....'

which is not necessarily true.  It is only true *if it happens to be the case that $b$ < $m$*, which is not required in general.  What *is* true is that $a$ and $b$ will have *the same remainder $r$* under the division algorithm (given $m$).